# Pasar consulta mongoDB a Mongoose

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

necesito pasar la siguiente consulta de MongoDb a Mongoose:

```
db.propiedads.find({
  _id:ObjectId("5bb18cc42a8f2d23d8dfcd65"),
  "planes.plan":ObjectId("5bb565f6382cf30364b182e5")
 })
```

actualmente esta consulta se encuentra funcionando en la consola de mongo. ahora agrego el modelo mongoose que representa la colección en la que realizo la consulta:

```
'use strict'
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var tipos = ['CASA','DEPARTAMENTO','EMPRESA','CONDOMINIO'];

var PropertySchema = Schema({
  tipo:{
    type:String,
    enum:{values:tipos, message:'Tipo de propiedad no valida'}
  },
  direccion: {
    comuna: {
      type:String,
      required:true
    },
    calle:{
      type:String,
      required:true
    },
    numero:{
      type:Number,
      required:true
    },
    departamento: String},
  id_usuario:{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref:'Usuario',
    required:true
    },
  fecha_inscripcion:Date,
  fecha_actualización:Date,
  planes:[
    {
      plan:{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:'Plan',
        _id : false
      },
        create:Date
      }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Propiedad' ,PropertySchema);
```

espero que me puedan ayudar, de todas formas muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En id_usuario.type y planes.plan.type debería ser `Schema.Types.ObjectId` en lugar de `Schema.ObjectId`

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
Propiedad.find({
  _id: "5bb18cc42a8f2d23d8dfcd65",
  "planes.plan": "5bb565f6382cf30364b182e5"
});
```